# How to create read-only user for schemas which can be created in the future?

Tags: postgresql

SO and Internet contains a lot of answers to question how to create read only user (for example see [this](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-create-read-only-user.html) article), BUT all of them promote the following way:

1. Create user
2. Grant `USAGE` privilege to **all existing** schemas
3. Grant `SELECT` privilege to **all existing** tables in **all existing** schemas
4. Grant default `SELECT` privilegie to **all tables** (which can be created in the future) for **all existing** schemas

But what to do if some schemas can be created in the future too?

I mean I want to grant read only permissions to these schemas (and tables in these schemans) created in the future without any additional configuration. Is it possible?

Comment: Grant proper permissions in event trigger?

Comment: I suppose it will works but it's looks like hard solution for such simple problem.

Comment: Are there some **existing** schemas for which future tables must **not** be granted on?

Comment: No, read-only user should have read-only access to **all schemas** and **all tables**.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify `template1` to grant read only permissions to all future schemas.

```
/connect template1
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO username;
```

Now all future `CREATE DATABASE` statements will also have the read only permissions applied to them.

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname; // is the same as CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template1;
```