# Postgres permission for new objects

Tags: postgresql, role, postgresql-11

Postgres version: 11

I've got 2 roles - one used for read and one for write on the same database.

```
CREATE ROLE reader WITH login;
CREATE ROLE writer WITH login;

CREATE DATABASE thedatabase;

GRANT SELECT ON all tables in schema public TO reader;
GRANT INSERT ON all tables in schema public TO writer;
```

Everything is fine for all the existing objects in the database, but as soon as another object is created both users will need a `GRANT SELECT/INSERT` to be able to perform their duties.

Is there a config to overcome this?

Comment: You are looking for `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, see e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237472)

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you.