# How to GRANT the USAGE privilege on SCHEMAS that will be created in the future

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I need a role to access a schema owned by another role, which can be dropped and re-created in the future. For the first part of my requirement, i.e. for an existing schema, the following would do:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA existing_schema TO my_role;
```

For the second part of the requirement, i.e. for schemas that don't exist yet but could be created in the future, the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` command, as documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), looked promising:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE my_role
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS TO my_role;
```

but it doesn't work as expected, i.e. after creating a new schema owned by another user:

```
CREATE SCHEMA new_schema AUTHORIZATION other_role;
```

and trying to access it as `my_role` I get:

```
my_role=> SELECT * FROM new_schema.some_table;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema new_schema
```

What am I doing wrong here?

PS I am aware of [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/250542/221150) but modifying system databases, such as `template1` is not an option for me since I am neither the owner nor the only user of the database cluster in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES needs to be for the role who will be creating the schema, so it needs to be `FOR ROLE other_role`.

Comment: My `CREATE SCHEMA` will get executed by yet another role, say `admin_role`, so the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` actually needs to be issued for the role that will be the **owner** (as opposed to the creator) of the `new_schema`, but your answer works perfectly nonetheless.